External configuration file in Spring Boot with Docker Compose Unable to Load
I'm trying to import a file using "spring.config.import". I saw in the documentation that you can import in 2 ways. 1 using multiple files (configtree) and the other is where the file is a .yaml file.
I've seen issues from others, but they're using configtree and I'd like to use yaml file instead because it can store multiple variables more easily IMO:

Using external config in spring boot application within docker-compose

When running the app, it always says:
Config data resource 'file [config/backend-secrets.yaml]' via location 'file:./config/secrets.yaml' does not exist

Here is a simple compose file that I have
services:
  backend:
    image: ghcr.io/acemint/something:main
    container_name: backend
    environment:
      SPRING_CONFIG_IMPORT: file:./config/backend-secrets.yaml
    secrets:
      - backend_secrets
    volumes:
      - ./config/secrets/:/config


Your environment variable is pointing at ./config, relative to the current directory, but your bind mount is at /config, an absolute path.

Thanks, I've found that actually it is not because of the relative path, but it' actually due to the workdir in my Dockerfile

Solution: Change the path of the yaml to the WORKDIR of your Dockerfile
volumes:
  - ./config/secrets/:/app/config

Explanation:
Given a simplified version of my Dockerfile below, I'm running my .jar on /app, which automatically means that while it seems that the app is trying to search from /config, it is searching from /app/config. Hence the volume should be mounted to /WORKDIR/....
# syntax=docker/dockerfile:1
FROM eclipse-temurin:21-jdk-alpine as build

# Set cwd to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the executable JAR file from the build stage
COPY --from=build /app/target/x-admin-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT*.jar /app.jar

# Define the default command to run the Spring Boot application
CMD ["java", "-Dserver.port=${PORT}", "-Dspring.profiles.active=production", "-jar", "/app.jar"]

